# Why does my ajax response return 0 rather than the file attachment preview?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need your help. I have a messaging system where users can attach files. But my ajax request keeps returning 0 rather than showing the preview of the uploaded file.

Here is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() 

{ 
    jQuery('#message_attachment').on('change', function() {

        var fromID  = $.cookie('_user_directory_id');
        var toID    = $.cookie('friends_username');

        close_urlfetched_message();

        $("#attachmentform").ajaxForm({

            beforeSubmit: function() 
            {
                $('#attached_file').html('<img src="'+site_url+'img/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...." title=""/>');
            },
            target: '#attached_file',
            url: site_url+'includes/wall.functions.php?type=22&from=' + fromID + '&to=' + toID,
            success: function(response) 
            {
                $('#attached_file').html('');

                if (response != "") 
                {
                    $('#attached_file').fadeIn(100).html(response);
                } 
                else
                {
                    $('#attached_file').fadeIn(100).html('<div id="message_info">Sorry, file attachment was unsuccessful.<br><br>Please try again or contact this site admin to report this error message if the problem persist. Thanks...</font></div>');
                }
            }
        }).submit();
    });
```

and here is my php function

```
    else if( $rtype == 22) // upload file in message
{
    $path = "../views/media/pictures/uploads/message_attachment/";

    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
         $name = $_FILES['attachedFile']['name'];
         $size = $_FILES['attachedFile']['size'];

        $allowedExtensions = unserialize (VALID_FILE_FORMAT_MESG);

        foreach ($_FILES as $file) 
        {
          if ($file['tmp_name'] > '' && strlen($name)) 
          {
              if (!in_array(end(explode(".", strtolower($file['name']))), $allowedExtensions)) 
              {
                  echo '<div id="message_info">'.$txt_var_185.'</div>';
              }
              else
              {
                  if( $size<(FILE_SIZE_FOR_MESG*FILE_SIZE_FOR_MESG))
                  {
                        $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                        $actual_image_name = time().rand(1234,9876).substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;

                        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachedFile']['tmp_name'], $path . $actual_image_name))
                        {
                            mysqli_query($DBConnection, "insert into `messages_attachments_temp` values('', 
                                                                                    ".mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnection, strip_tags($_GET["from"])).", 
                                                                                    ".mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnection, strip_tags($_GET["to"])).", 
                                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnection, strip_tags($actual_image_name)."")."', 
                                                                                    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnection, strip_tags(date('d-m-Y')))."',
                                                                                    '', 
                                                                                    '', 
                                                                                    '', 
                                                                                    '', 
                                                                                    ''
                                                                                    )");

                            ######## show all images
                            $checkfor_attachments = mysqli_query($DBConnection, "select * from `messages_attachments_temp` 
                                                                 where 
                                                                `from` = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnection, $LoggedID)." and 
                                                                `to`   = ".mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnection, strip_tags($_COOKIE["friends_username"]))." AND file !='' 
                                                                 order by `id` asc");

                            if( mysqli_num_rows($checkfor_attachments) > 0)
                            {
                                while( $getall_attachments = mysqli_fetch_array( $checkfor_attachments ) )
                                {
                                    $file = $getall_attachments["file"];
                                    $id   = $getall_attachments["id"];

                                    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                                    $rembutton = '<a href="javascript:;" class="temp_img_remve_small" onclick="remove_temp_message_image('.$id.');">x</a>';

                                    if( $ext == "gif" || $ext == "GIF" || $ext == "JPEG" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "jpg" || $ext == "JPG" || $ext == "png" || $ext == "PNG" )
                                    {
                                        echo '<span class="img" id="mesgfile'.$id.'">'.$rembutton.'<img src="'.BASE_URL.'views/media/pictures/uploads/message_attachment/'.$file.'" width="73" height="60"></span>';
                                    } 
                                    else if($ext == "doc" || $ext == "docx" || $ext == "rtf")
                                    {
                                        echo "<span class='img' id='mesgfile".$id."'>".$rembutton."<a href='".BASE_URL."views/media/pictures/uploads/message_attachment/".$file."' target='_blank'><img src='".BASE_URL."img/doc.png' width='75' height='60'></a></span>";
                                    }
                                    else if($ext == "pdf")
                                    {
                                        echo "<span class='img' id='mesgfile".$id."'>".$rembutton."<a href='".BASE_URL."views/media/pictures/uploads/message_attachment/".$file."' target='_blank'><img src='".BASE_URL."img/pdf.png' width='75' height='60'></a></span>";
                                    }
                                    else if($ext == "txt")
                                    {
                                        echo "<span class='img' id='mesgfile".$id."'>".$rembutton."<a href='".BASE_URL."views/media/pictures/uploads/message_attachment/".$file."' target='_blank'><img src='".BASE_URL."img/txt.png' width='75' height='60'></a></span>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "<div id='message_info'>".$txt_var_121."</div>";
                        }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      echo "<div id='message_info'>".$txt_img_up_size."</div>";
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
              echo "<div id='message_info'>You just canceled your attachment.</div>";
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dataType : 'html'

```
$("#attachmentform").ajaxForm({

        beforeSubmit: function() 
        {
            $('#attached_file').html('<img src="'+site_url+'img/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...." title=""/>');
        },
        target: '#attached_file',
        dataType : 'html',
        url: site_url+'includes/wall.functions.php?type=22&from=' + fromID + '&to=' + toID,
        success: function(response) 
        {
            $('#attached_file').html('');

            if (response != "") 
            {
                $('#attached_file').fadeIn(100).html(response);
            } 
            else
            {
                $('#attached_file').fadeIn(100).html('<div id="message_info">Sorry, file attachment was unsuccessful.<br><br>Please try again or contact this site admin to report this error message if the problem persist. Thanks...</font></div>');
            }
        }
    }).submit();
```

Comment: Thanks :) , please accept/upvote my answer @RomeoHennessy